# Sharing visualizations and analysis with google-analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, android-sdk-2.3

How to have more than one user edit the same report?
In google-analytics, there are many customizations available.  Is it possible to reliably share these customizations so that several users on a project are looking at the same document? For example, if I make a dashboard widget, or a shortcut, or a customized report (with, e.g. multiple tabs) -- I would like to be able to share this with other users on the project. When they make changes (e.g. add a tab), I'd like to see this, too.  Is there a good way of doing this?
The hacky way would be to have several people share the same account. I would like to avoid this, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not, Dashboard views are bound to individual Google Accounts.
The solution you suggested of using a shared User account sounds like the most straight way. The alternative being Sharing Dashboard iterations for other users to apply to their own accounts.